# Using the Debugger Effectively in Multithreaded Code (SBCL)

Tags: multithreading, debugging, common-lisp

In a basic single-threaded program, the debugger is invoked when an error condition is not handled. However, in a multithreaded program the debugger prints the error, but the program continues on with the other running threads. I'd like to be able to break/stop at the error to examine the stack frames, etc, in the relevant thread. The SBCL Manual talks about using `sb-ext:*invoke-debugger-hook*`. Can someone explain how to use this, or otherwise any guidelines for effectively troubleshooting run-time errors in multithreaded code?

EDIT: I've looked at the other related post at [Handling an exception in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502921/handling-an-exception-in-a-thread), but the problem I'm experiencing is a little different. The program never actually enters the debugger, although it does print out the relevant error message saying the debugger was invoked before continuing on:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:INVALID-ARRAY-INDEX-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "lparallel" RUNNING {1006B183D3}>:
  Invalid index -1 for (SIMPLE-VECTOR
                        0), should be a non-negative integer below 0.
```

The only way to (momentarily) interrupt subsequent processing is with CTRL-C giving:

```
restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Return from SB-WIN32::SIGINT.
  1: [ABORT   ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

But processing then continues, and the only serviceable continuation from this point is 1 = ABORT (0 is ignored). I'm looking for a way to enter the debugger.

Comment: See [(SB-THREAD:RELEASE-FOREGROUND)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41502921/124319)

Comment: When you get into the debugger with control+c, you can evaluate any code at the debugger prompt, including `(sb-thread:release-foreground)`, which should bring up the debugger for the other thread. After you handle that condition, you'll be returned back to the debugger in the first thread.

Comment: @jkiiski, thanks for the simple clarification.